# Microphone on combo jack not working Asus A46CM

Tags: microphone

My laptop Asus A46CM has a microphone/headphone combo jack. I try to attach my samsung earphone that has a microphone on it, but the microphone not working, Ubuntu still use the laptop microphone with very bad noise. On Windows the microphone working well, how to fix this on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to System Settings > Sound > "Input" tab, and make sure the correct microphone input is selected and not muted.

Comment: After I choose the microphone instead of the Internal microphone, my earphone not working, but the microphone sounds very bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug that needs to be solved.

A temporary workaround: install and run pulse audio control gui (apt-get install pavucontrol). In the input devices mute the external microphone and unmute the internal microphone. For me the internal microphone is listed as "unavailable" but it works when you unmute.